# Pyspark - spark-submit to an AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have created an EMR cluster (emr-5.36.0) in AWS with the default sparks components (Spark 2.4.8, Hive 2.3.9).
I have installed Pyspark (3.3.0) on an EC2, in an python virtual environment.
From there, I would like to run "spark-submit" commands to the EMR cluster.

To test the command, I am using python the code at the bottom of [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-application.html)

To configured the YARN_CONF_DIR environment variable on the EC2, I copied the yarn-site.xml file from /etc/hadoop/conf.empty/ on the EMR's master node to a folder on the EC2.

But now, on the EC2, when I try to run spark-submit, I get:

```
$ export YARN_CONF_DIR=/home/me/spark/   
$ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster spark_test.py   
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/shaded/javax/ws/rs/core/NoContentException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.timeline.TimelineUtils.<clinit>(TimelineUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceInit(YarnClientImpl.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1327)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1764)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.shaded.javax.ws.rs.core.NoContentException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 13 more 22/07/18 18:36:25 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

And from here I am basically lost. I tried to google the error but I am still not clear what the error is about. Did I miss a step? An environment variable maybe?

Ultimately, I want to use the SparkSubmitOperator in Airflow, but I figured I should get the "native" command to work first before using the operator (which is just a wrapper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do YARN_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop_files/ locally, the content of the folder hadoop_files needs to be the content of the EMR's /etc/hadoop/ folder, not /etc/hadoop/conf.empty/.